# Eslint rule for banning usage of `function.name` and `constructor.name`?

Tags: eslint

Is there an eslint rule that forbids the use of the `name` property of a function?

When you minify code it typically mangles a function's name. So in development, `myFunc.name` will be `'myFunc'`, but in production it will be something like `'a'`. This is a development footgun and I would like to prevent this.

[eslint-plugin-ban](https://github.com/remithomas/eslint-plugin-ban) only applies to call expressions, but I want something that applies to accessing the property (MemberExpression).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bit different eslint plugin https://runebook.dev/en/docs/eslint/rules/no-restricted-syntax

I use it to warn `constructor.name` usage having the following eslint rule setting (yaml syntax):

```
  "no-restricted-syntax":
    - warn
    - selector: MemberExpression[object.property.name='constructor'][property.name='name']
      message: "'constructor.name' is not reliable (can become 'E', 'P' and etc.) after standard angular production build (JavaScriptOptimizer)."
```

PS: there is a tool https://estools.github.io/esquery/ for debugging ES AST queries that can be used for `no-restricted-syntax`

**UPDATE:**
There is even more convenient tool to debug the syntax rules:
https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.7.2&sourceType=module&showAST=es